# My For Each Loop doesnot work when I host

Tags: javascript, foreach

My code works in the live server of VS code but when I hosted it on Github pages it gave me and error. It seems to work fine and all of my code seems to work and I found no errors whatsoever.

[link to the hosted page](https://kaflekundan.github.io/cryptoworld/)

[link to the code](https://github.com/KafleKundan/cryptoworld/)

```
    // news parameters
const Api_Key = "...";
const category = "crypto";
const url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines"
// https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?q=crypto&apiKey=4d2ac6c2f603440a864065a48836b9f7
let newsAccordian = document.getElementById('newsAccordian')


// grab the new container
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

xhr.open('GET', `${url}?q=${category}&apiKey=${Api_Key}`, true)

xhr.onload = function () {
    let json = JSON.parse(this.responseText)
    let articles = json.articles
    console.log(articles) // error is shown in this line
    let allNews = ""
    articles.forEach(function(news,index) {
        let newsContent = news.content.substring(0, news.content.length - 14);
}
xhr.send();
```

Comment: Look in the console. If you get CORS errors you likely cannot do what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the console, you get the following error:

```json
{"status":"error","code":"corsNotAllowed","message":"Requests from the browser are not allowed on the Developer plan, except from localhost."}
```

If you want to use this api outside your computer, you have to purchase licence.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because articles is not fetched completely before `forEach` method execute so

```
console.log(articles);//undefined
```

is `undefined`. Make sure your data from api is fetched completely before using `forEach`. You can use `async` `await` or `promise` to fetch data from api.